# ERROR 18080 --- [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application startup failed Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I know question like this have been already asked but I am new to spring boot and trying to run this program as java but getting error. I tried to search this error on google but didn't find any useful also I am using java 1.8.0_221

**console:**

```
.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.2.RELEASE)

2022-04-25 11:32:30.547  INFO 18080 --- [           main] i.j.springbootstarter.CourseApiApp       : Starting CourseApiApp on LAPTOP-UG1V1711 with PID 18080 (started by sanjeev in D:\spring boot\course-api)
2022-04-25 11:32:30.550  INFO 18080 --- [           main] i.j.springbootstarter.CourseApiApp       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-04-25 11:32:30.607  INFO 18080 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@41005828: startup date [Mon Apr 25 11:32:30 IST 2022]; root of context hierarchy
2022-04-25 11:32:31.130 ERROR 18080 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: io.javabrains.springbootstarter.CourseApiApp
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:419) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:266) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:281) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-context-org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at io.javabrains.springbootstarter.CourseApiApp.main(CourseApiApp.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>io.javabrains.springbootquickstart</groupId>
  <artifactId>course-api</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Java Brian Course Api</name>
  
  
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
  
  
  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  
  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>
  
</project>
```

and this is my main class:

```
package io.javabrains.springbootstarter;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CourseApiApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CourseApiApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Spring Boot 1.4.2 is very old, and has been out of support for a very long time. You should change to a newer version like 2.6.7 and see if it works better for you. https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#learn

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue. I am also studying from the same channel. Replace "1.4.2" version with "2.1.0" and update the maven project and run the code. It will work.